# Domain using objects in Odoo8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In my custom model have a one2many relation.Fields are like,

***.xml**

```
<field name="o2m_field>
  <tree>
   <field name="a"/> // many2one relation
   <field name="b  domain=[('name','=',a.second_field)]/> // many2one relation
   <field name="c"/>
   <field name="d"/>
 </tree>
```

***.py**

```
_name='a.a'
_columns ={
            'name':fields.char('Name'),
            'second_field':fields.char('Second field')
}
```

But getting an `JS` error:Error: AttributeError: object has no attribute 'second_field'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access second_field directly in domain.

You should create second_field related store False and use in domain.

Ex:

```
  second_field=fields.Char(related="a.second_field",store=False,readonly=True)

  <field name="b"  domain=[('name','=',second_field)]/>
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 1):

in the client side when you using `attrs`, `domain` or `context` you cannot use field that are not listed in the same view (even if exists in the Model class), this is why you need always to pass this values to the client side like in this case as `Emipro Technologies Pvt.` suggested use related field.